# Субстантивация порядкового числительного

Tags: грамматика, числительные

Какой частью речи является выделенное слово "два" в следующем тексте

*Составь пароль 244466666 и сообщи его друзьям, - "один **"два"**, три "четыре", пять "шесть"*?

И как тут должно быть: **один** "два" или **одна**?

Comment: Я не сразу понял смысл предложения при такой трактовке числа. Наверное, лучше диктовать его так: "... двойка, три четвёрки, пять шестёрок".

Comment: @Alex_ander это да, но тогда исчезает юмор.

Comment: Кто-то видит здесь порядковое числительное?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На мой взгляд, чтобы числительное оставалось собой, а фраза была более-менее верно построена, без утери юмора, следует записать так:

> Составь пароль 244466666 и сообщи его друзьям: один - два, три -
>   четыре, пять - шесть.

Имеется в виду опущенное *"раз по"*, то есть *"один раз по (цифре) два", три раза по четыре"*. Но всё равно это настолько условно смотрится в записи, а на слух воспринимается ничуть не лучше, что эта шутка имеет мало прав на существование, сколько голову не ломай.
Правда, до сих пор не понимаю, причём тут порядковые числительные.

Answer (score 0):

Если без юмора, то "два", как и большинство прочих числительных, ничем, кроме числительного, быть просто не может. Тысяча, миллион и т. д. могут в некоторых случаях быть признаны существительными, но вряд ли здесь. *Два* - числительное в любом контексте, если только оно не забрано в кавычки и/или перед ним не стоит слово "цифра" (*цифра "два"*) или что-то подобное.

Это если говорить о частях речи. Вот по поводу членов предложения - вопрос действительно был бы непростым.

Comment: "Два" тут как раз в кавычках.

Comment: Ой, а зачем в кавычках? Я не посмотрела... Если в кавычках, но это название, имя существительное,  но здесь кавычки не нужны.

Comment: Абсолютно согласна с IrinaGL, что  в данном примере "два" - это, Артём, существительное. Ставим правильно вопрос. Поэтому фраза будет звучать так: однО - два, три...и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Доброго дня!
Разумеется, "два" - числительное. А вот что касается рода, я нахожу более корректным "одна "два" - как бы смешно ни звучало, говоря "одна "два" и "три "четыре", мы просто опускаем существительное "цифра" ("одна [цифра] "два").